# Google Cloud Function frozen for over minute

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

have a strange thing happening running a Google cloud function. The function starts and logs the user id and job id as expected. Then it calls firestore db and basically sits there for 1 minute, sometimes 2 before it executes the first call... It was even timing out on 240 seconds.

```
 const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    
 admin.initializeApp();
    
 exports.run = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    
        var id = data.id;
        var userid = data.uid;
        var retry = data.retry;
    
        var project;
        var db = admin.firestore();
        var storage = admin.storage();
    
        console.log("Starting Collect");
        console.log("UID: " + userid);
        console.log("id ID: " + id);
    
        // Times out on this call 
        db.collection("users").doc(userid).collection("ids").doc(id).get().then(function(doc) {
            console.log("Loaded DB");
            project = doc.data();
            createexport();
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            error('Loading DB Error, ' + err, false);
        });
    
    
        function createexport() {
            db.collection("exports").doc(id).set({
                status: 'Collecting',
                stage: 'Export Checker',
                percent: 0,
                id: id,
            }).then(function() {
                console.log("Creating Export");
                setdb();
            }).catch(function(err) {
                error("Error creating export in database :" + err, true)
            });
        }
    
        function setdb() {
            db.collection("users").doc(userid).collection("ids").doc(id).update({
                status: 'Analyzing Files',
                stage: 'Collecting'
            }).then(function() {
                getaudio();
            }).catch(function(err) {
                error("Error updating users id in database :" + err, true)
            });
        }
    
        function getaudio() {
            const from = userid + '/projects/' + project.originalproject.id + '/audio.' + project.originalproject.extension;
            const to = userid + '/' + id + '/audio.' + project.originalproject.extension;
            storage.bucket('---------').file(from).copy(storage.bucket('---------').file(to)).then(function() {
                console.log("Collecting files");
                copy2();
            }).catch(function(err) {
                error('Collecting Audio Error, ' + err, true);
            });
        }
    
        function copy2() {
            const from = userid + '/projects/' + project.originalproject.id + '/overlay.png';
            const to = userid + '/' + id + '/overlay.png';
            storage.bucket('--------.appspot.com').file(from).copy(storage.bucket('---------').file(to)).then(function() {
                updateexport();
            }).catch(function(err) {
                error('Collecting Overlay Error, ' + err, true);
            });
        }
    
    
        function updateexport() {
            db.collection("exports").doc(id).update({ status: "Waiting" }).then(function() {
                console.log("All files collected");
                return { status: 'Success' };
            }).catch(function(err) {
                error("Error creating export entry in database :" + err, true)
            });
        }
    
    
        function error(evt, evt2) {
            AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" });
            var html;
            var sub = 'Error with id ' + id;
            console.log(evt);
    
            if (evt2) {
                db.collection('users').doc(userid).collection('ids').doc(id).update({
                    status: 'Error'
                }).catch(function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
                db.collection("exports").doc(id).update({
                    status: 'Error',
                    stage: 'Collecting',
                    error: evt,
                }).catch(function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
    
                html = `
                        Username: ${project.username} <br>
                        UserID: ${userid} <br>
                        Email: ${project.email} <br>
                        id: ${id}
                        `
            } else {
                html = `id: ${id}<br>
                        UserID: ${userid} <br>
                        Message: Error logged was: ${evt}
                        `
            }
    
            var params = {
                Destination: {
                    ToAddresses: [
                        'errors@mail.com'
                    ]
                },
                Message: {
                    Body: {
                        Html: {
                            Charset: "UTF-8",
                            Data: html
                        },
                    },
                    Subject: {
                        Charset: 'UTF-8',
                        Data: sub
                    }
                },
                Source: 'errors@mail.com',
                ReplyToAddresses: [
                    project.email
                ],
            };
            var sendPromise = new AWS.SES({
                apiVersion: "2010-12-01",
                "accessKeyId": "-----------",
                "secretAccessKey": "------------------------",
                "region": "--------",
            }).sendEmail(params).promise();
    
            sendPromise.then(function(data) {
                return { data: data };
            }).catch(function(err) {
                return { err: err };
            });
        }
    });
```

Seems to me to be way too long for a database call of only a few kb. I will attach the cloud log to show time difference. After this initial slump it then performs as expected.
[Cloud log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A5ip.jpg)

Anyone got any ideas as to why this could be happening? Many thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Your function is appearing to hang because it isn't handling promises correctly.  Also, it doesn't appear to be sending a specific response to the client app.  The main point of callable functions is to send a response.

I suggest reviewing the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#sending_back_the_result), where you will learn that callable functions are required to return a promise that resolves with an object to send to the client app, after all the async work is complete.

Minimally, it will take a form like this:

```
    return db.collection("users").doc(userid).collection("files").doc(id).get().then(function(doc) {
          console.log("Loaded DB");
          project = doc.data();
          return { "data": "to send to the client" };
    }
```

Note that the promise chain is being returned, and the promise itself resolves to an object to send to the client.

Comment: Hi Doug. The code did extend on from there quite a bit, but it always works once it gets past this initial database call. I was missing a return before my last function though, I will give it a go and see what happens. Thanks for you reply.

Comment: Hi Doug, I updated the post to include the rest of the code. Adding return before the last function like   return function updateexport()   caused the function not to get past the console.log("id ID: " + id); section.